# PHP/Codeigniter erro "Array to string conversion"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

Fiz um foreach para ir adicionando valores a um insert mas de repente apareceu um erro **Array to string conversion** estranho e não faço ideia do que seja.

```
public function distribuicaoprodutos(){
        $filiais=json_decode($_POST['filiais'],TRUE);
        $dados=json_decode($_POST['dados'],TRUE);
        $insert="INSERT INTO movimentacao (Filial, Quantidade) VALUES ";
        $i=0;
        foreach($filiais as $key => $value)
        {
            $i++;
            if($value!="" && strlen($filiais)>$i) //linha de erro
            {
                $insert.="('".$key."','".$value."'),";  
            }elseif($value!="" && strlen($filiais)==$i){
                $insert.="('".$key."','".$value."')";
            }   
        }


    }
```

Comment: Qual a linha do erro?

Comment: alterei a pergunta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para medir o tamanho de um array, a função a ser utilizada é `sizeof`, e não `strlen` (que mede o tamanho de strings).

Segue uma sugestão de alteração para seu código:

```
public function distribuicaoprodutos()
{
    $filiais = json_decode($_POST['filiais'], true);
    $dados   = json_decode($_POST['dados'], true);
    $insert  = "INSERT INTO movimentacao (Filial, Quantidade) VALUES ";
    foreach ($filiais as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $insert .= "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "'), ";
        }
    }
    $insert = substr($insert, 0, -2);
}
```

Comment: Sobre o sizeof você está certo mas o porque deu usar o if é porque no array filias tem campos vazios e não posso cadastrar eles

Comment: Entendi. Fiz outra edição com base no seu comentário :)

Answer (score 2):

Use o [**count()**](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php) ou [**sizeof()**](https://www.php.net/sizeof) para obter tamanho de arrays.
No seu código pode fazer cache do valor do tamanho da array $filiais fora do loop para evitar chamar a função count() a cada iteração.

Teste assim:

```
 $i=0;
 $filiaisTamanho = count($filiais);
 foreach($filiais as $key => $value){
            $i++;
            if($value!="" && $filiaisTamanho>$i) //linha de erro
            {
                $insert.="('".$key."','".$value."'),";  
            }elseif($value!="" && $filiaisTamanho==$i){
                $insert.="('".$key."','".$value."')";
            }   
        }
```

Mas na verdade, se é só por causa da ultima virgula, e não tem mais código que precise do contador `$i`, então pode usar assim:

```
foreach($filiais as $key => $value){
    if ($value != "") $insert.= "('".$key."','".$value."'),";
}
$insert= rtrim($insert, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Ele está dizendo que vc está tentando usar um array como uma string
Os dados que estão vindo via POST estão em formato json, até aí, ok, mas qual é a estrutura deste JSON ? Isso é de suma importância para tratar este problema.

Neste caso, recomendo dar um print_r() ou um var_dump() no $_POST['filiais'] e no $_POST['dados'] e verificar em que formato está este json para que se possa tratar de maneira adequada.

Outra coisa que eu aconselho é utilizar o Active Record do CodeIgniter ( [Aqui](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) ) para fazer este insert, e realizar o tratamento do insert ANTES, e não durante a execução dele.

Falo isso porque é preferível tratar antes ou montar a estrutura do que será inserido antes do que durante o processo de inserção.

Se você postar este json ou mais ou menos a estrutura dele, talvez eu consiga ser mais preciso na minha ajuda

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: sinto muito mas não é isso... o erro era que eu estava usando strlen ao invés de sizeof, mas mesmo assim valeu..

Answer (score 1):

Uma versão do seu código mais reduzida.

```
public function distribuicaoprodutos(){
        $filiais=json_decode($_POST['filiais'],TRUE);
        $dados=json_decode($_POST['dados'],TRUE);
        $insert="INSERT INTO movimentacao (Filial, Quantidade) VALUES  ";
        foreach($filiais as $key => $value)        
            $insert.="('".$key."','".$value."'),";                     
        $insert = substr($insert,0,strlen($insert)-1); // retirar a ultima virgula;         
}
```

Comment: amigo, faltou o if que verifica se o valor está vazio...